# How does hardware limit the maximum number and resolution of monitors usable via Remote Desktop?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop, resolution

I want to use Remote Desktop on Windows 7 with multiple monitors (as opposed to spanning), and I understand that both ends need to be running Windows 7 Ultimate or Enterprise editions. (Or, Windows Server 2008 R2.)

**But how does *hardware* limit the maximum number and resolution of monitors?**

For example, the graphics cards on the host (if that's the correct term) can't have anything to do with the display on the client, can it? But, going further then, are the *only* limitations basically what's allowed by the protocol (in the O/S) and/or configured by local/group settings? Or are there actual hardware-dependent limitations (excluding network-related, *i.e.* bandwidth).

Let's make the question more concrete. I inherited a gamer's desktop computer with 4 DVI ports (that can supposedly support up to 8 monitors via DVI splitter cables), and I want to use this computer to work remotely from the other coast.

**What exactly do I need to find out about (1) my host machine, (2) my client machine, and/or (3) my company's infrastructure and settings,** for someone to tell me definitively, "You can support up to __ monitors of __ x __ resolution."?

Thanks very much in advance. (Also, please note that I do try to accept answers; unfortunately for 3 of 5 questions I've asked, there have not been any suitable answers to accept thus far.)

Comment: It's worth noting you only need Ultimate on the remote end.  Regarding your actual inquiry, I have no clue how this works having never tried to go much beyond the native capabilities of the remote system...I *believe* it only cares what your client machine can do and everything else is irrelevant but I'm not sure.  I may try to set up a test later today if I have time...

Comment: You only need both machine to be W7 Ultimate\Pro\Ent in case if you want to RDP in both directions. If you need RDP to a single host, then you should have W7 U\E\P on it, but client machine you connect from doesn't have to be Enterprise or Ultimate, since you can RDP from any client with rdp-client installed (either Windows\Linux\Unix host).

Comment: How many monitors does your host machine have?